# facebook signed_request user_id missing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is data of signed_request:

```
Array
(
    [algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256
    [issued_at] => 1331219385
    [page] => Array
        (
            [id] => xxxx602xxx551
            [liked] => 1
            [admin] => 1
    )

[user] => Array
    (
        [country] => at
        [locale] => de_DE
        [age] => Array
            (
                [min] => 21
            )

    )

)
```

but user_id is missing ...

is this because user dont gave permission to the app?
I thougt an app can access all data which is public, like name or user_id

is there a way to get "user_id" without a basic permission?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will not be able to get any identity of user prior to connection with application, this is just not possible.

You need to authorize the user to get his user id